# 'data:,' in the address bar while using chromedriver 2.22 , chrome 51, and selenium 2.53

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to run a simple c# statement using chrome driver with selenium but every time it navigates to data:, tab without going to the specified url

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:/Libraries/");
driver.Url = "http://www.hotmail.com";
```

Comment: In my usage, I have notice that `data:,` appears in the address bar for a few seconds before the actual URL does, so that is probably not relevant to the problem. More to the point, I have the exact same versions of Chrome, ChromeDriver, and Selenium, but my tests work. Please provide some more details, preferably a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: Do you see Chrome's loading icon animating at all? How long did you let it run?

Comment: it navigate to data:, tab and after few seconds a warning appears saying "the visual studio project has stopped working" and when i debug i found this error (The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:22974/session timed out after 60 seconds.) in ( IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:/Libraries/"); ) Line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means the same but try
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://hotmail.com")

Comment: i tried this line still does not navigate to the url

Comment: it navigate to data:, tab and after few seconds a warning appears saying "the visual studio project has stopped working" and when i debug i found this error (The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL localhost:22974/session timed out after 60 seconds.) in ( IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:/Libraries/"); ) Line of code

Comment: I noticed slash in your path to web driver is incorrect. Id replace it with \. Like c:\libraries\

Comment: that was one of the answers i found over the internet. to replace \ with / .. but same error in both cases :(

Comment: Ok. If it's possible downgrade driver version to 2.21 and .net bindings to 2.51  or 2.52. Selenium periodically release newe version with such error.

Comment: Here, the same... I´m using chromedriver-2.22.exe and Chrome 51.0.2704.106. WebDriver open up the browser, but it stucks with "data:," in the address bar. Then, after a few seconds, the log shows Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
I´m using Java here, JDK 1.7, and Selenium 2.53.1.